# Strategy for breaking up a scalar product equality

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

Given is the equality

$$\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}=c$$ What is the strategy for breaking up the scalar product and express either $\vec{A}$ or $\vec{B}$?

I know one strategy, say $\vec{A}$ is a constant vector and $\vec{B}$ is the position vector $\vec{x}$:$$\vec{A}\cdot\vec{x}=c$$ Take gradient of both sides: $$\nabla(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{x})=\nabla c,$$ then $$\vec{A}=\nabla c$$

Do you have a strategy for doing this when both $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are not constant? How do we eliminate $\vec{A}$ form the LHS and express $\vec{B}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the scalar product definition, you have that  given vector A, vector B will lie anywhere in a subspace normal to A, with distance  $B_A$ from the origin. $B_A$ is the  projection of B onto the direction of A, and the condition is $|A| |B_A| = c$.

Say vector N is normal to vector A, then $B = (c/|A|^2)A + N$. This holds for any vector N normal to vector A; hence only the component of B into the direction of A is determined  by your equation $A B = c$.

Comment: Only asked how can it be done algebraically. Can one "divide" away A from the left hand side and be left only with B. I have been thinking about how it can be done but my ideas are so far limited :)

Comment: No you can't. Say vector N is normal to vector A, then $B = (c/|A|^2)A + N$.

Comment: thank you, your expression for B answers my question! Could you include it in the text of your answer and I can mark it answered

Comment: Yes -- I 've included it.